# How to detect multiple clicks in a row on a button - like android developer options

Tags: android, gesture

I would like to implement the a similar behaviour to android settings app of the developer options. I mean when a user clicks on a button for a 7 times in a row with a small delay between every click a popup will appear ask him to enable an hidden feature in the app.

How can I implement this behaviour?

Comment: On each click increase a counter :) If you want to check for the time save also a time variable and compare with it and on each click update the it. If the time is longer than predefined time interval, just start counting from 1 again.

Comment: I thought maybe there is a something which is already implemented by system like double click or long click :)

Comment: Well there might be, but It seems faster to just write it sometimes :)

Comment: @kirotab as the good solution, but you have to add a timer when the button is clicked, so when a click is too far after the previous one it restarts to 0 instead of pursuing the count.

Answer (score 5):

I have developed it based on the watchdog concept. An instance of `TimerWatchDog` does the job if it doesn't refresh in the specified time. `ContinuousClicksHandler` uses an instance of `TimerWatchDog` along with counting the clicks.

### Usage:

```
val clicksCount = 7
val maxInterval = 1000L

val continuousClicksHandler = ContinuousClicksHandler(clicksCount, maxInterval)

continuousClicksHandler.registerCallback(object : ContinuousClicksHandler.ContinuousClicksCallback {

    override fun onContinuousClicksSuccessful() {
        println("onContinuousClicksSuccessful!")
    }

    override fun onContinuousClicksFailed() {
        println("onContinuousClicksFailed!")
    }

})

button.setOnClickListener {
    val count = continuousClicksHandler.click()
    showToast("Needs ${clicksCount - count} more clicks to succeed!")
}
```

**ContinuousClicksHandler.kt**

```
/**
 * @author aminography
 */
class ContinuousClicksHandler(
    private val clicksCount: Int,
    maxInterval: Long
) {

    private var callback: ContinuousClicksCallback? = null
    private val timerWatchDog = TimerWatchDog(maxInterval)
    private var currentClicks = 0

    fun click(): Int {
        if (++currentClicks == clicksCount) {
            timerWatchDog.cancel()
            currentClicks = 0
            callback?.onContinuousClicksSuccessful()
        } else {
            timerWatchDog.refresh {
                currentClicks = 0
                callback?.onContinuousClicksFailed()
            }
        }
        return currentClicks
    }

    fun registerCallback(callback: ContinuousClicksCallback) {
        this.callback = callback
    }

    interface ContinuousClicksCallback {

        fun onContinuousClicksSuccessful()

        fun onContinuousClicksFailed()
    }

}
```

**TimerWatchDog.kt**

```
import java.util.*

/**
 * @author aminography
 */
class TimerWatchDog(private val timeout: Long) {

    private var timer: Timer? = null

    fun refresh(job: () -> Unit) {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = Timer()
        timer?.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() = job.invoke()
        }, timeout)
    }

    fun cancel() = timer?.cancel()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this OnClickListener. It works with 7 continuous clicks with less than 500ms between each click. Basically, we just remember the number of clicks and the time of the last click and work with that. Shouldn't be too hard to understand and/or modify.

```
...
view.setOnClickListener(continuousClickListener);
...


private final View.OnClickListener continuousClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    private long lastTimeMs = 0;
    private int clickCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (lastTimeMs == 0 || now - lastTimeMs < 500) {
            lastTimeMs = now;
            clickCount++;
            if (clickCount >= 7) {
                // do stuff
                showToast("quiz enabled");
            } else {
                if (clickCount > 2) {
                    showToast((7-clickCount) + " more for quiz");
                }
            }
        } else {
            lastTimeMs = 0;
            clickCount = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your smart code.
I've noticed a tiny bug. It happens when you click once, then wait more than 500ms then click again. This second click was not taken into account. So I adapted a little your code. NOTE: I removed the counter indication because I don't need it.

Here's the code:

```
private final View.OnClickListener continuousClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        private long lastTimeMs = 0;
        private int clickCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (lastTimeMs == 0 || now - lastTimeMs < 500) {
                lastTimeMs = now;
            } else {
                lastTimeMs = 0;
                clickCount = 0;
            }
            clickCount++;
            if (clickCount >= 7) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Connection with test profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.v(TAG, "clickCount=" + clickCount);
        }
    };
```

Thanks !